# Wordpress PVC mouting issue lost+found in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

i am using GKE kubernetes cluster and created the wordpress docker image.

Docker file:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.1-apache
COPY /web /var/www/html
RUN ls
WORKDIR /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Deployment.yaml

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-content-data
          mountPath: /var/www/html/
```

When i try to mount a pvc with this docker image all the data inside it going empty and folder 'lost+found' added to path. i want all the data inside 'html' folder in PVC and also when new deployment come of wordpress data should be there only changed filer will overwrite.

i am also thinking to add CI/CD for docker image so please suggest answer to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check any of the online docs to deploy wordpress? Something like this : https://medium.com/@containerum/how-to-deploy-wordpress-and-mysql-on-kubernetes-bda9a3fdd2d5

Comment: it's not helping anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in `Dockerfile`

Working dockerfile is like

```
FROM wordpress:php7.1-apache
COPY /web /usr/src/wordpress
WORKDIR /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

have to use this path `/usr/src/wordpress` instead `/var/www/html`

> GitHub documentation:
>   https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/master/php7.1/apache
>
> Docker-hub documentation : https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good articles, describing how to configure and deploy  wordpress on GKE with data persistence.

[Deploying WordPress and MySQL with Persistent Volumes on GKE](http://gmacario.github.io/2018/10/17/deploy-wordpress-mysql-on-pvc.html) works fine. You can use this manual as an example of successful installation.